# PyCharm - Apple Silicon

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been using the "normal" version of Pycharm on a Mac Air successfully - I downloaded the Apple Silicon version a few days ago when prompted, when offered "performance improvements".

I naively assumed it would be seamless, but I'm now having issues with a couple of existing projects I've tried to run. The switch seems quite disruptive - is there an easy fix?

Example:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.abi3.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.abi3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.abi3.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: I suspect you just need to rebuild your virtual environment so that appropriate shared libraries can be installed (assuming they are available) or rebuilt.

Comment: I would recommend trying to download python 3.9 since python 3.9 runs natively on the M1 chip and python 3.8 does not. Perhaps the Apple Silicon version of pycharm relies on python 3.9 somewhere.